# Kafka Connect JMX metric for trace field in RestAPI response

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, jmx

Today when I hit the `/status` in my connector, using the `curl`, I got `trace` field with a detailed error when my connector is down.

But I didn't find any similar field in JMX metrics (https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/monitoring.html). Any tips on how to get this information by metrics?

Comment: `trace` is a stacktrace, which is text, not a metric. Are you looking for number of failed tasks? If so, various `failure-total` counts are on the worker metrics...

Comment: No, I'm looking for the detail about why it has failed.

Comment: Why would that be a metric? Metrics are mostly numeric values, not long strings of text... If you want searchable log output, then setup Elasticsearch/Splunk log forwarding from the `connect.log` files rather than use the status endpoint